# Why magento 2 Setup/Uninstall Script ONLY deletes modules installed through Composer?

Tags: magento2, eav, entity-manager

Why Magento 2 Setup/Uninstall Script ONLY deletes modules  installed through Composer? I am not able to understand the reason behind this!

Answer (score 0):

Composer and Magento are two different tools. Magento uses composer, but Magento does not make use of composer functionality. So when you delete a module in the context of Magento, it is correct not to remove it from the composer.json.

It is just not the purpose of the command.